# URL encoding a SPARQL query for dbpedia.org

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, url-encoding

I am trying to write a code (in ABAP) for URL encoding a SPARQL query for dbpedia.org.

Is there any reference code or method?

Ex: Input:

```
select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100
```

Output:

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3FConcept+where+%7B%5B%5D+a+%3FConcept%7D+LIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on
```

Thanks
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about ABAP.

Having said that, I'd be surprised if there isn't a library function to do that.  If not, you can try porting the one from the JDK:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/net/URLEncoder.java#URLEncoder